# CS:GO server is ignoring settings in server.cfg

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I have just installed CS:GO server on a Linux VPS. I have set up steam account and everything in the `~/csgo/csgo/server.cfg`. The server clearly reads the file correctly, since it shows correct server name and requires the password that I have set. However setting any game settings is ignored. This is the config:

```
hostname "XXXXXX"
sv_setsteamaccount "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
log on
sv_logfile 1
sv_password "XXXXX"
sv_enablevoice 0


mp_endwarmup_player_count 2
mp_autoteambalance 1
mp_friendlyfire 1
mp_freezetime 120
mp_forcecamera 1
mp_autoteambalance 0
mp_autokick 1
mp_friendly_grenade_damage 1
mp_buytime 1000

cash_player_interact_with_hostage 700
cash_team_loser_bonus_consecutive_rounds 1000
```

Everything under `sv_password` is ignored. When I query the values when the server is running, I can see that they were overridden or ignored. Is it possible that other config is overwriting my settings? What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `server.cfg` is executed prior to the `gamemode_competitive.cfg`, due to this any game mode settings defined the `server.cfg` are overwritten once the competitive config is executed. To edit game mode settings you will have to edit the `gamemode_competitive.cfg` or the respective gamemode's cfg file you are playing.

gamemode cfg files available in path `csgo\csgo\cfg` directory:

`gamemode_casual.cfg`
`gamemode_deathmatch.cfg`
`gamemode_custom.cfg`
`gamemode_armsrace.cfg`

etc..

so move all your mentioned settings to one of the above mentioned cfg.

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT edit the `gamemode_competitive.cfg` like the other answer suggests, because it is overwritten every time you update the server.

Valve [documentation](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Dedicated_Servers) explicitly says

> Admins should not modify the `gamemode_XXX.cfg` files

Instead create a `gamemode_XXX_server.cfg` and place your overrides there.